# How to remove brackets and quotes using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a list of artists that is formatted like so:

['Justin Bieber']

['Brockhampton']

etc

and I want to make it so these variables no longer have quotes or brackets and instead look like:

Justin Bieber

Brockhampton

How would I do this?

Comment: Additionally, this dataset contains many other variables, but I am fine with how they are formatted.

Comment: Do all values in the variable have the [' '] around them? Or at least all of the non empty values?  Do any of the values themselves contain the single quote? If so are they doubled up?  What about the other two characters? Do they appear in any of the values?

Answer (score 2):

Use the compress function.

```
=compress(artist, "[']");
```

The second argument adds both square brackets and the quotation mark to the list of characters to remove.

I'm doing this entirely from memory and it's years since I used SAS, so it might struggle with the quotation mark inside the quotation marks. You could also try

```
=compress(artist, '[]', 'p');
```

where the third argument adds all punctuation marks to the list of characters to remove.

Anyway, the compress function is what you want. Experiment with it if the exact arguments above don't quite work!